# Solving a separable differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have an equation:$$\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dt}=kP\left(1-\frac PM\right),$$and we need to find $P(t)$ given the initial $P(0)$. Here $k$ is a constant and $P$ represents population, $M$ represents maximum population.

I tried to use separable differential equations, but I am slightly confused. There is a hint:$$\frac M{P(M-P)}=\frac1P+\frac1{M-P},$$and I need to simplify as far as possible. I have tried to use separable equations but I cannot seem to get the hint equation. I think the main issue is trying to get all $P$'s on to one side.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP\left(1-\frac{P}{M}\right)$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP\left(\frac{M-P}{M}\right)$$

$$\left(\frac{M}{P(M-P)}\right)\frac{dP}{dt}=k$$

$$\left(\frac1P+\frac{1}{(M-P)}\right)\frac{dP}{dt}=k$$

$$\int\left(\frac1P+\frac{1}{(M-P)}\right)\,dP=\int k\, dt$$

Edit:

$$\ln \left(\frac{P}{M-P} \right)=kt+c$$

when $t=0$, $P=P_0$, hence $c=\ln \left(\frac{P_0}{M-P_0} \right)$

Comment: After taking the integrals of both sides, would you isolate for P in order to get P(t)?

Comment: After taking integation, I should get an arbitrary constant, I will then use the initial condition to solve for the constant.

Comment: When i integrate i get ln (P(M-P))= kt+c, if i do P(0) i get ln (P(M-P))=c is that suppose to represent the constant? and does P(t) = kt + ln(P(M-P))

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I still do not know what to do, after solving and getting c how would the whole equation be for P(t)?

Comment: If you wish, you can take exponential function on both sides, and multiply $M-P$ on both sides, by then, we get a linear equation in $P$ and we can solve for $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint,

$$\left(\frac1P-\frac1{M-P}\right)dP=\frac kMdt$$

and

$$-\log\left(\frac MP-1\right)=\frac kMt+c.$$

You can draw $P$.